# Im getting error on magento backend

Tags: magento

An error occured while rewriting "seller/adminhtml_product_edit_tabs_Edit_grid" : "The original class "Mage_Seller_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Edit_Tabs_Edit_Grid" does not exist" (rewriter: "eval")

Comment: You're trying to extend a class that doesn't exist.  Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a third party grid customization extension in Magento like BL_CustomGrid you should remove the entries in the table `customgrid_grid` that storing the grid id you modified. Please try the datascript code as below:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$conn = $installer->getConnection();
$conn->query("DELETE FROM `customgrid_grid` WHERE `module_name` like 'your_module_name'");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Under the - System -> Custom Grids -> List -> Manage Custom Grids Delete this  entry

**seller/adminhtml_product_edit_tabs_Edit_grid**